# Certificate based authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, certificate

I am trying to implement certificate based authentication. But I am continuously getting these messages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1

https://www.thetechplatform.com/post/certificate-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core-web-api

[image]

Comment: Getting prompted to pick a client certificate seems like success to me... what do you think isn't working correctly?

Comment: even after doing the selection , same is happening.

Comment: From the screenshot you shared, seems the application running in kestrel. Could you download the repo from the blog and running in vs2022, and check if the issue will happen agin.

Comment: For this kind of issue, we need to collect the network trace file and check what happend in your application. You also could enbale the log level to Information, and try to find some useful things in logs.